# How to create the first DB in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have just installed Postgres 12 on a Mac. As you may soon appreciate I am totally new to it.

During the installation process I was asked to provide a "password". I do not remember specifically, but I think it was for the some sort of admin role.

Now I want to create my first database. Reading the documentation I insert the command

```
createdb myfistdb
```

the system asks for a password. I give the one I set during the installation processes but I got the following error

```
createdb: error: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "myusername"
```

where `myusername` is the user I am logged in.

The same happens if I give the system password of `myusername`.

I understand that my question is pretty basic, but I have been struggling quite some time without any success, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to reset the password, if yes and it still fails, just restart it and try to login again

Comment: Try logging in as the `postgres` user, not the `myusername` one

Comment: You need to provide the DB user name with the ```-U``` option. Here are the docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-createdb.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database uset name used by `createdb` defaults to the operating system user name, so you'll have to specify the administrative superuser explicitly:

```
createdb -U postgres myfistdb
```